# How to set Spark MemoryStore size when running in IntelliJ Scala Console?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, fedora-25

I am running Spark code as script in Intellij (CE 2017.1) Scala Console on Linux 64 (Fedora 25). I set SparkContext at the start:

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
val conf = new SparkConf().
  setAppName("RandomForest").
  setMaster("local[*]").
  set("spark.local.dir", "/spark-tmp").
  set("spark.driver.memory", "4g").
  set("spark.executor.memory", "4g")

val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

But the running SparkContext always starts with the same line:

17/03/27 20:12:21 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.1.0

17/03/27 20:12:21 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 871.6 MB

17/03/27 20:12:21 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 192.168.1.65:38119 with 871.8 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.1.65, 38119, None)

And the Executors tab in the Spark web UI shows the same amount. 
Exporting _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms2g -Xmx4g" from the terminal before start also had no effect here.

Answer (score 8):

The only way to increase Spark MemoryStore and eventually Storage memory Executors tab of web UI was to add -Xms2g -Xmx4g in VM options  directly in Intellij Scala Console settings before start.

[image: Intellij Scala Console for Spark]

Now the info line prints:

17/03/27 20:12:21 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 2004.6 MB

17/03/27  20:12:21 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 192.168.1.65:41997 with 2004.6 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.1.65, 41997, None)

and the Spark web UI Executors tab Storage Memory shows 2.1 GB.