# Unable to convert text format to parquet format through spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive

I am trying to insert a partition's data from one table (text format) to another table (parquet format) using spark framework. The data is around 20gb and the configuration I am using to do so is:

master = yarn

deploy-mode client

driver memory = 3g

executor memory = 15gb

num executors = 50

executor cores = 4

I am using below piece of code to do it:

```
val df = spark.sql("select * from table1")
df.repartition(70).write().mode("append").format("parquet").insertInto("table2")
```

Everytime I try running this, after completing certain tasks, the job fails with java-heap space issue.

Based upon the size of data, and spark configuration I have specified, I am not sure if there is anything that I am missing here because of which the job is failing. Any help towards this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest to try to set -Xms -Xmx JVMs parameters as well

Comment: What is the number of files in the source?

Comment: @slesh ..won't executor memory serve the same purpose?

Comment: @bdcloud .. It's 113

Comment: @MohitRaja, I am not sure, but I'd try to specify Xms, Xmx directly not relying on the spark configuration

Comment: One option is to increase driver memory and also please post stack trace of the error that you are encountering.When you say few tasks are completed you mean some of the files converted to parquet in destination ? Also the source files are Gzipped?

Comment: @bdcloud, I am not able to fetch yarn logs since the app ID is no longer there in history server, but yes, what I know is that it was a java heap space issue. When I say few tasks got completed, it meant that job completed certain tasks for its very stage and failed in between, without converting any files.

I increased driver (10gb) and executory memory (30gb) further. It is completing now, but takes around 12 minutes to convert 20 GB of data

Answer (score 0):

You have to set JVM parameters:

[How to set Spark MemoryStore size when running in IntelliJ Scala Console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43054268/how-to-set-spark-memorystore-size-when-running-in-intellij-scala-console)

Official info:

> Spark properties mainly can be divided into two kinds: one is related
>   to deploy, like “spark.driver.memory”, “spark.executor.instances”,
>   this kind of properties may not be affected when setting
>   programmatically through SparkConf in runtime, or the behavior is
>   depending on which cluster manager and deploy mode you choose, so it
>   would be suggested to set through configuration file or spark-submit
>   command line options; another is mainly related to Spark runtime
>   control, like “spark.task.maxFailures”, this kind of properties can be
>   set in either way.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html